# Unable to trace the origin of intent redirection vulnerability issue

Tags: android-security

I understand what is an intent redirection vulnerability issue. Also, aware of the solutions. But I am facing trouble finding the origin of this issue. Play console is reporting that the error lies here `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult`.

I am using AppcompactActivity throughout the app. So I have checked every startActivityForResult in my app. None of them are forwarding an unsafe intent. I think this is from some third-party library, I am using many of them. Play console is not giving me much information. So I am unable to find the root of this security threat.

Are there any tools/methods to trace the intent redirection vulnerability issue? Especially if it is originating from a third-party library, how can we trace it? After applying the fix, how can we ensure the issue is resolved before submitting it to the Play-console?

Comment: Hi friend, I have the same problem, you managed to find the solution, I've been researching it but I'm still being rejected in the store.

Comment: Rijo - Facing same issue. Any updates? It will be of great help.

Comment: Hello friend, any updates on this? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Hi Friends, I have same problem, any Updates? it will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 3):

I am also faced the same issue. I have contacted Google Play support for more details. But the same replay was obtained.
The possible remedies are to use some App Scanner to find Security Vulnerabilities. On search I have got some software for this job. The article which helped me was ["Mobile App Scanner"](https://geekflare.com/mobile-app-security-scanner/). From the list I have found this one very useful- [Mobile Security Framework (MobSF)](https://mobsf.github.io/docs/#/). Installation procedure is also there in this link.
I have scanned my app using this one and got some valid vulnerabilities which helped me to pass the Google Play Policy hurdle.
Hope someone found this helpful.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue, Can you tell me what are all the major vulnerability you fixed to pass through the Google Play policy